# duplicate key in DB that is not really duplicate

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbcontext, duplicates

I have a MVC web App with EF (code first).

In my "import" function, I want to add a list of items into my DB (DbContext item with DbSets).

With a "foreach" loop, I try to add each item to DB and save.

```
    public static void AddItem(Item item)
        {
            ItemService.AddItem(item);
            UOW.Commit();
        }
```

and -

```
  //UOW
  public void Commit()
        {
            m_context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Since maybe some of the items already exist in the DB, I put "AddItem" in "try-catch" block, so if it fails to add the item - it will continue to the next item.

The problem is that it works well as long as the items are **not** in the DB. If there is an item that already exist - I get an error that it can't add a duplicate key, and than I get this error for **all the next items** (also items that does not exist in DB)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that your context is still the same when you get to the next Commit? Because then your newly added item would still be there (it was never removed after all) on the next Commit and fail again.

If your import function isn't running in multiple threads a simple solution could be to check if the item to add is already present in your database before actually adding it to your context.